# A Gorenstein domain that is not a complete intersection

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, gorenstein

Could you give me an example (with proof) of a Gorenstein domain that is not a complete intersection?

Comment: I think maybe this paper answers your question (though he does not construct an explicit example, only proves existence): http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.nmj/1118798875

Comment: Explicit examples can be extracted from his construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical example of Gorenstein domain which is not a complete intersection comes form the Buchsbaum-Eisenbud structure theorem of Gorenstein ideals of grade $3$ (see Bruns and Herzog, Theorem 3.4.1).

Let's take a skew-symmetric matrix $X$ of size $2r+1$ whose entries are indeterminates over a field $K$. The ideal $I_{2r}(X)$ generated by all $2r$-pfaffians of $X$ has height $3$ and is minimally generated by the set of $2r$-pfaffians, so it has $2r+1$ generators and no less. Moreover, the quotient ring $R=K[X]/I_{2r}(X)$ is a Gorenstein domain. (For more details one can look [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869380901404).) Now, if $R$ would be a complete intersection ring, then the ideal $I_{2r}(X)$ would be generated by a regular sequence (of length at most $3$). If we take $r>1$, this is not possible.

Comment: there should be a simpler example, something that uses only the theorems from matsumura

Comment: I invite you to find one.